# Need to print only once outside the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print "True" if the input string has two consecutive identical letters. Foe ex: a="Matthew".For this input it should print True since the word 'Matthew' has two consecutive identical letters ("t"). Similarly print False for the word "John" since it has no consecutive letters.

## Code:

```
 a="Matthew"

 for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i]==a[i+1]:
       print("True")
    else:
       print("False")
```

Output:
      False,
      False,
       True,
      False,
      False,
      False

Just needed to print only once "True" if there are consequtive letters and needed to print only once "False" if there are no consequtive letters.

Answer (score 3):

use an other variable

```
a = "Matthew"
double = False

for i in range(len(a)-1):
   if a[i] == a[i+1]:
      double = True
      break

print(double)
```

Comment: instead of another variable,  can we do with break statement?

Comment: No need to parse the entire string if we know the first two characters match, e.g. `s = 'aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Answer (score 3):

Just for posterity's sake, I thought you might find it interesting to know that regex offers a much more concise solution:

```
a = "Matthew"
if re.search(r'(.)\1', a) :
    print("MATCH")
else:
    print("NO MATCH")
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has `for-else` loop.
So, it can be done this way too:

`a = "Matthew"`

```
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i]==a[i+1]:
          print("True")
          break
    else:
         print("False")
```

Output: `True`

The `else` part executes only when the `for-loop` has iterated through the range; any `break` in between will lead to skipping the execution of `else` part.

So, if the input were `a="Mathew"`, it will print `false`